# Twitter Bootstrap Dropdown Menu Doesn't Appear

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Unlike most people who have trouble getting the Twitter Bootstrap [Dropdown menu](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#dropdowns) to work, I can't even get it to appear in any of my browsers (e.g. Chrome 26).  It will only appear if I remove the "dropdown-menu" property from the  class attribute.  All of the code within the dropdown div was cut-and-pasted directly from the documentation page.  I've used all of the surrounding code with all of the "Scaffolding" and "Base CSS" examples and they worked just fine.  If I view the source, I can see the code is there.  It just doesn't display in my browser unless I remove the "dropdown-menu" property.  I downloaded Bootstrap a week ago so I'm using a recent version.  BTW, I did completely clear out all my browser settings and restart.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Components | Dropdowns</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <!-- Link or button to toggle dropdown -->
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I haven't had time to test it out yet as I'm in the process of upgrading a server.  I will try it tomorrow and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Ahhhh, now I understand.  Thank you PSL!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add a trigger to the dropdown:-

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K6NtG/)

```
 <div class="dropdown">

    <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="drop4" role="button" 
     data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown 
      <b class="caret"></b></a> <!--Here-->
 
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When you remove the class `dropdown-menu` it appears because it just appears the `ul` as is with some styling.

or just add this `$('.dropdown-menu').toggle();` with out trigger.